# Python Pygame print keystroke spams the output

Tags: ubuntu, pygame, pycharm, python-3.8

I have been following a
Pygame tutorial on made on 2019 so it might be outdated.
It should detect the arrow keys and print it but it keeps spamming the print right or left arrow and the keystroke released when i press any arrow key.
is the code outdated or is there a mistake on my code?
And also before it start the spamming it says "ALSA lib pcm.c:8526:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred" on the pycharm as an error.
It works great for all the other parts.

video link if you need (https://youtu.be/FfWpgLFMI7w?t=2458)

im using pygame 2.0.0 on pycharm 3.8.5 if its the same on pycharm and python.
Linux ubuntu 20.04.1

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        print("Left arrow")
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        print("Right arrow")
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        print("Keystroke released")
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `pygame.key.set_repeat(…)` to enable repeated key press events?

Comment: I checked and i am not using pygame.key.set_repeat(…).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why it's not working, I tried rewriting the code and I have no errors, try with what I wrote:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
running = True

# initializing main loop
while running:
  # initializing event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                print("Left arrow")
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                print("Right arrow")
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                print("Keystroke released")
        
     # lines in order to close up the window properly
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False

pygame.quit()
```

Hope it will works for you, see you.

Comment: It works great now. I just had to move the "if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False" to the end of the loop. Thanks alot!